# EfCore nested list with other AggrgateRoot relation in DDD Pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I Have a problem with DDD structure I think I don't understand the pattern well.

My Database ERD:
[App Orders ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyfml.png)

brief.
I have three AggrgateRoot (AppOrders - AppTests - AppAntibiotics).
AppOrders has nested list AppOrderItems Linked (one to one) With AppMicrobiologicalReportResults (Ef table per type) every item has three list (Sensitive - Intermediate - Resistant) AppAntibiotics (many to many Relation) between AppMicrobiologicalReportResults and AppAntibiotics here is the problem

question.
how can I extract this output with best practice by Ef Core query and not conflict with DDD Pattern

```
{
    "sample": "string",
    "pusCells": "string",
    "gramStainedFilms": "string",
    "znStainedFilms": "string",
    "aerobic": "string",
    "viableCount": "Mild growth",
    "mycobacterialCulture": "string",
    "mycologicalCulture": "string",
    "sensitiveItems": [
      {
        "antibioticId": 2,
        "antibioticName": "Amoxicillin" //<== here is my problem
      },
      {
        "antibioticId": 1,
        "antibioticName": "Penicillins" //<== here is my problem
      }
    ],
    "intermediateItems": [],
    "resistantItems": [],
    "testId": "1dfa0d50-4ed8-fb4d-5ed3-3a0f8876cf1e",
    "testName": "Microbiological Report",
    "status": 0,
    "resultDate": null,
    "resultPrinted": false,
    "price": 0,
    "id": "20557835-bcdd-1cb4-ef22-3a0f887707ba"
  }
```

some notes.
1- I am using Abp Framework , Netcore 7, SqlLite
2- This The Owner Action Method

```
public async Task<MicrobiologicalReportResultDto> GetMicrobiologicalReport(Guid id,Guid itemId)
    {
        
        var itemsQuery = await _itemsRepository.WithDetailsAsync();
        itemsQuery = itemsQuery.Where(x => x.OrderId == id && x.Id == itemId);

        var testQuery = await _testRepository.GetQueryableAsync();
        
        // This is Antibiotic Query
        var antibioticsQuery = await _antibioticsRepository.GetQueryableAsync();

        var query = 
            from item in itemsQuery 
            join test in testQuery 
                on item.TestId equals test.Id
            select new { item, test};

        var entity = await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(query);

        if (entity is null)
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }
        if (entity.item is not MicrobiologicalReportResult)
        {
            throw new BusinessException("Error Types");
        }

        var rc = ObjectMapper.Map<MicrobiologicalReportResult,MicrobiologicalReportResultDto>(
            entity.item.As<MicrobiologicalReportResult>());
        
        rc.TestName = entity.test.Name;

        return rc;
    }
```

3- this is the ef fluent api configurations

```
        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Sensitive)
            .WithMany()
            .UsingEntity<MicrobiologicalAntibiotic>("MicrobiologicalReportSensitiveAntibiotics",
                l=>l.HasOne<Antibiotic>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c=>c.AntibioticId),
                r=>r.HasOne<MicrobiologicalReportResult>()
                    .WithMany(x=>x.SensitiveItems)
                    .HasForeignKey(c=>c.OrderItemId));

// Others Removed for lack of complexity
```

4- this is Sql I write to test

```
select * from AppOrderItems itemsQuery
left outer join AppTests testsQuery
on testsQuery.Id = itemsQuery.TestId
left outer join MicrobiologicalReportSensitiveAntibiotics sens
on sens.OrderItemId = itemsQuery.Id
left outer join AppAntibiotics antbiotic 
on sens.AntibioticId = antbiotic.Id
```

I apologize if something is not clear.

thanks alot for you.

I tried linq group into but it's confused while it needs sub lists Queryables

Comment: The entities have navigation properties. Use them, or add them where needed. I.e. don't `join`. As for *not conflict with DDD Pattern*, that's very vague and disputable. EF's class model is a data layer, not a domain model.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, I think two things in your question need to be considered:

1. Your query spans multiple aggregates. Should you put it in one method? Or should you split it into multiple pieces and gather the results in the client code (like you did in the question)? If you put it into one method, where do you put the query method? Which repository should define it? If you are having a bad performance, I think you should make it one method to optimize the query, and a good solution might be to use a new fabric repository for this query.
2. What are you going to do with the query result? Is it for reports or do you operate on the result and modify it? If it's read-only, you should consider **CQS**. CQS (or CQRS if you can split the write and read database) goes well with the DDD. DDD focuses on the write-model. Checking invariants is for modifying data (commands in CQS), not reading them. If you are not familiar with CQS, it says that you should separate your commands (requests that modify your data) from queries (requests that don't modify any data known as read-only queries). This way you achieve separation of concerns and you can focus on problems more efficiently. Specifying another model for your read-only purposes helps you optimize your model for queries. In that sense, these queries won't pollute your repositories. On the read model, you define another DbContext to be read-only and you can even define navigation properties for the aggregate roots to reference each other. The point is that it is not gonna modify data, so no need to worry about invariants.